# Google Sheets - limit possible person's name appearance

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to limit possible name or phrase appearance?

[Link to my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/120Pk1hb56eAMbK44f01xxzkEpWDYwHQwXBxP_ym-uQE/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to restrict possibility of choosing same name for let's say more than 10 times. Will you please help? :)

Comment: Where are users choosing names? How is that done? On what tabs?
Please update your sheet permissions to "Anyone with link can edit"

Comment: Ok, sorry, i couldnt answers earlyer. Ive changed permission to edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me if this is what you need.

Additionally you should add a trigger so that every time you edit the function it is activated.

```html
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedRange = e.range;
  var editedRow = editedRange.getRow();
  var editedCol = editedRange.getColumn();
  
  // Checks if the edit was made in column A and in a row greater than 1
  if (editedCol == 1 && editedRow > 1) {
    var editedValue = editedRange.getValue();
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var values = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + (editedRow - 1)).getValues();
    
    if (values.flat().indexOf(editedValue) !== -1) {
      Browser.msgBox("This value already exists in column A");
      editedRange.clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, ill try it and let you know if thats what i meant. Thank you very much. 